# Sonar INVALID HASH, but the expected and download hashes are identical

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

After upgrading to 5.1, Sonar shows INVALID HASH error when downloading the jdbc driver. This happens when executing mvn sonar:sonar on any of our environements: bamboo, jenkins or our local machines. Tried this with sonar-maven-plugin 2.3 to 2.6. The file downloads successfully and even has the expected hash.

This is the error message:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXX: INVALID HASH: File /Users/XXXX/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache5136138904337145345.tmp was expected to have hash 4aab6e384bf857f02073daf51b96b967
 but was downloaded with hash 4aab6e384bf857f02073daf51b96b967
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: INVALID HASH: File /Users/XXXX/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache5136138904337145345.tmp was expected to have hash 4aab6e384bf857f02073daf51b96b967
```

It is strange that the error message has a newline after the hash, but the jdbc-driver.txt has no newlines, even did a hexdump to make sure.

The jdbc-driver.txt

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar|4aab6e384bf857f02073daf51b96b967
```

hexdump -C jdbc-driver.txt

```
00000000  6d 79 73 71 6c 2d 63 6f  6e 6e 65 63 74 6f 72 2d  |mysql-connector-|
00000010  6a 61 76 61 2d 35 2e 31  2e 33 34 2e 6a 61 72 7c  |java-5.1.34.jar||
00000020  34 61 61 62 36 65 33 38  34 62 66 38 35 37 66 30  |4aab6e384bf857f0|
00000030  32 30 37 33 64 61 66 35  31 62 39 36 62 39 36 37  |2073daf51b96b967|
00000040  0a                                                |.|
00000041
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file jdbc-driver.txt seems to be corrupted. The trailing 0a is not expected. Are you using a king of HTTP proxy that may alter this file during download?

Comment: Thanks for the response! The file on the server has the trailing 0a, which is because jdbc-driver.txt was created using vi which adds the a0. Creating the file with a text editor (I used sublime) and swapping it out fixed the issue.